# how blade can access to defined varibles outside of itself

Tags: php, global-variables, laravel-blade, template-engine

i want to create a template engine with php regex

my template engine is the following code

```
<?php

    class tmp
    {
        public function assign($name,$val){
            $GLOBALS[$name]=$val;
        }
        public function compile($buffer){
            $buffer= '?> '.preg_replace('~\{\!\!\s*\$(\w+)\s*\!\!\}~', '<?php echo $GLOBALS["$1"]; ?>', $buffer);

            file_put_contents('compiled.php', $buffer);
            return $buffer;
        }
        public function run($run){
            return eval($run);
        }
    }

?>
```

and my theme is the following code

```
{!! $bar !!}
```

and compiled theme is

```
 ?> 
    <?php echo $GLOBALS["bar"]; ?>
```

I access to vars with $GLOBALS 
but in blade the compiled code is as follows

```
<?php echo $bar; ?>
```

how blade can access to defined vars directly with their name?

Comment: Look into laravel's source code

Comment: @CharlotteDunois laravel is too big and find a section is very hard -I looked but could not find them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't confirm this is how blade is doing it, though I suspect it would be, but basically extract does that exactly what you are asking:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

It takes an array of variables and inserts directly into the symbol tables so they be accessed directly. Used in combination with `get_defined_variables()` it becomes very useful.

Comment: If my Question was just get varibles , i could use $GLOBALS that used in my past code

Comment: Exactly - read my *whole* answer - `extract` would convert them to be available as `$bar` instead `$GLOBALS['bar']`. Extract inserts an array of values into the *symbol table*

Comment: No worries. Goodluck with the template engine